# in_array command does not work

Tags: php, insert, exists

in_array function, for some reason, return false;

This is the code i'm using:

```
$query = "SELECT users_invites.invite_user_id
          FROM users_invites
          JOIN users ON users.id = users_invites.user_id AND users_invites.user_id =". param('session_id')."
          ORDER BY users.id ASC";

$response = $this->_db->query($query)->result_array();

 foreach ($response as $key => $value)
 {
    if (!in_array($_REQUEST['invite_user_id'][$key],$response[$key]))
        $this->_db->insert("users_invites",array("user_id"=> param('session_id') , "invite_user_id"=>$_REQUEST['invite_user_id'][$key]));


 }
```

The in_array function dosen't work and the insertion command is always execute.
Any idea?

**P.S:** The invite_user_id is an array.
**Edit:** The response value is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [invite_user_id] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [invite_user_id] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [invite_user_id] => 3
        )

)
```

The $_REQUEST['invite_user_id'] Values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: `print_r($response);` and `print_r($_REQUEST['invite_user_id']);` = ?

Comment: Use var_dump before in_array to see what exactly is in Your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your resulting structure, I would do a `foreach` on the data to break it into single set of array with all the ids returned from the table.

From there I would `foreach` the `$_REQUEST['invite_user_id']` against the new array `$ids`, here is a sample:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($response as $item)
{
   $ids[] = $item['invite_user_id'];
}

foreach ($_REQUEST['invite_user_id'] as $id) 
{
    if (!in_array($id, $ids))
    {
        echo "{$id} was not found...\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "{$id} was found...\n";
    }
}
```

**[And here is a live DEMO.](https://eval.in/120862)**

Answer (score 0):

your request should be like this

```
$query = "SELECT users_invites.invite_user_id
          FROM users_invites
          JOIN users ON users.id = users_invites.user_id AND users_invites.user_id =". param('session_id')."
          ORDER BY users.id ASC";

$response = $this->_db->query($query)->result_array();

$invite_user_id = array();


 foreach ($response as $key => $value)
 {
   $invite_user_id[] = $value;
 }

 foreach( $_REQUEST['invite_user_id'] AS $key => $value )
 {
      if ( !in_array( $value,$invite_user_id) )
      {
       $this->_db->insert("users_invites",array("user_id"=> param('session_id') , "invite_user_id"=> $value));
      }
 }
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST['invite_user_id'][2]` will be undefined

Comment: try now updated define new variable of all array keys

Comment: I think the OP want to know if `invite_user_id` is in array. `array_keys` will return only the index, which will not represent the correct data to check.

Comment: yes yes correct ill update my answer wait , i got it

Comment: `isset($_REQUEST[$key][$value])` will be always `true`. Instead use `isset($_REQUEST[$key])`

Comment: you have to do duple loop first for keys second for check , i have updated the answer this should work fine

Comment: Please, always verify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The follow should work well:

```
$query = 'SELECT users_invites.invite_user_id
            FROM users_invites
            JOIN users ON users.id = users_invites.user_id AND
                 users_invites.user_id = ' . param('session_id') . '
        ORDER BY users.id ASC';
$response = $this->_db->query($query)->result_array();

$storedInvites = array();
foreach ($response as $index => $data) {
    $storedInvites[] = $data['invite_user_id'];
}

foreach ($_REQUEST['invite_user_id'] as $index => $inviteUserId) {
    if (!in_array($inviteUserId, $storedInvites)) {
        $insertData =  array(
            'user_id' => param('session_id'),
            'invite_user_id' => $inviteUserId
        );

        $this->_db->insert('users_invites', $insertData);
    }
}
```